# What is the current US policy on Hydrogen as "green fuel" and how is the current administration promoting it?

Tags: united-states, energy-policy

> Biden-Harris Administration Announces $7 Billion For America’s First Clean Hydrogen Hubs, Driving Clean Manufacturing and Delivering New Economic Opportunities Nationwide.

According to some estimates, this will increase global green hydrogen production by threefold.

What is the current US policy on Hydrogen as a "green fuel" and how is the current administration promoting it?

Comment: This question is open-ended and inviting speculation. It does not have a well-defined answer. Voting to close.

Comment: @quarague No! I want insights into the policy, I am not asking for opinion.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about trade. There is quite a lot of international trade already, or do you mean trade in Hydrogen?   Anyway, see https://www.energy.gov/eere/fuelcells/hydrogen-delivery Short answer, the strategy is to develop this infrastructure.

Comment: Hello. Note that we only allow questions that can be factually answered, with verifiable and defensible references. This is a Q and A platform. We're not a social media site that foster discussions and debates, and so we do not allow open-ended questions that invite speculative opinions. Your question here has been temporarily closed because it invited speculative opinions (I have edited your Q to correct this) and didn't have any references. When you ask questions here, you need to back any claims with references in it too. So add those and ask for the Q to be reopened and we'll do it. Thanks

Comment: I think that using hydrogen as fuel-like energy storage is a specific enough area and the US is a small enough political entity that this question can in principle be easily answered by citing some official announcements and summarizing them. Not close-worthy, but maybe not that interesting. "Green" Hydrogen is still not playing any substantial role.

Comment: Hydrogen is an energy storage mechanism, not a fuel source, that competes directly with batteries. It's not practical for cars, but it might make more sense to power larger vehicles with set routes like trucks and ships.

Comment: @SurpriseDog Thanks for pointing that out. I do not know much about the subject (hydrogen as fuel / storage) and I was the one who had edited the post and included the reference to "green fuel". If you are knowledgable about the subject, and feel that is erroneous, please edit the question and correct it. (Take care not to change the original question though).

Comment: The big problem with Hydrogen fuel cells is that Hydrogen, when mixed with oxygen, has a tendency to... explode... which is a violation of the U.S.'s strict automotive safety standards.  I do recall seeing a 60 Minutes article on a chassis for a Hydrogen Fueled car that was functional in Summer of 2007, so the tech does exist.  Aside from the problems with the explosions, it was noted that the range on a full tank was below that of a conventional engine for the time AND the infrastructure investment (changing gas pumps to hydrogen pumps is difficult).

Comment: Hello everyone! This article https://www.energy.gov/articles/biden-harris-administration-announces-7-billion-americas-first-clean-hydrogen-hubs-driving interested me to ask this question, my question is asking details about such investment in green hydrogen. It's motivation and strategy of US.

Comment: Most probably the US government has a strategy there. One just needs to find it and cite it. Also using hydrogen as fuel is not as dangerous as it was in the past. It's already used as such for around 20 years. See for example [Fuel cell vehicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_cell_vehicle).

Answer (score 1):

Currently Green Hydrogen production is not competitive with gray, thus in order to promote Green Hydrogen it must be supported with funding. Under [The Inflation Reduction Act of 2022 (IRA)](https://www.energy.gov/eere/fuelcells/financial-incentives-hydrogen-and-fuel-cell-projects) there are many benefits for the producers of Green Hydrogen. Most notably is tax credit with up to $3.00/kilogram of Green Hydrogen created. The detailed list of incentive can be found in the link.

With respect to policy, it should be noted that IRA is not restricted to Green Hydrogen but rather it is quite wide and covers many Green energy alternatives. Not sure I understand what is referred by *"Hydrogen as a "green fuel"*. I think with respect to Hydrogen the focus is primarily to Greenify (decarbonize) the gray hydrogen now being used in the industry (above 90%) and little Hydrogen trucks/privates before aspiring something else.

Your link provides yet another link for the U.S [roadmap with respect to Hydrogen](https://www.hydrogen.energy.gov/library/roadmaps-vision/clean-hydrogen-strategy-roadmap) which [includes 99-page document](https://www.hydrogen.energy.gov/docs/hydrogenprogramlibraries/pdfs/us-national-clean-hydrogen-strategy-roadmap.pdf) which includes this figure:

[image]

According to which - the main focus of Hydrogen is to decarbonized several industries. Interestingly, they also want Hydrogen for power generation (maybe storage hubs to take advantage of grid arbitrage) - but as the figure shows - they aim to use the hydrogen directly in some industries that need (or rather will need) Hydrogen.

Comment: Using something as fuel means using it to provide the energy to move things. Like fuel cells in automobiles.